# How to use st_difference with two mulipolygon dataframes

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I have two dataframes:

- C:  multipolygon dataframe with 938 observations of city centers around Europe

```
structure(list(URAU_CODE = "UK003C1", URAU_CATG = "C", CNTR_CODE = "UK", 
    URAU_NAME = "Leeds", CITY_CPTL = NA_character_, CITY_KERN = NA_character_, 
    FUA_CODE = "UK003L2", NUTS3_2016 = "UKE42", FID = "UK003C1", 
    geometry = structure(list(structure(list(list(structure(c(-1.30856, 
    -1.31534, -1.32275, -1.32915, -1.33497, -1.33948, -1.34465, 
    -1.34273, -1.34815, -1.35481, -1.36189, -1.37032, -1.37491, 
    -1.38162, -1.39005, -1.39984, -1.40281, -1.40914, -1.41356, 
    -1.41878, -1.42973, -1.43349, -1.43206, -1.43122, -1.43435, 
    -1.44039, -1.44546, -1.45087, -1.457, -1.46519, -1.46824, 
    -1.47537, -1.48156, -1.48919, -1.49338, -1.50091, -1.51023, 
    -1.51632, -1.52139, -1.52854, -1.53624, -1.54346, -1.54936, 
    -1.55252, -1.55699, -1.56283, -1.56768, -1.58542, -1.5868, 
    -1.59288, -1.60172, -1.60713, -1.61198, -1.62302, -1.62787, 
    -1.63787, -1.64221, -1.64855, -1.65357, -1.65503, -1.66514, 
    -1.67046, -1.67997, -1.68458, -1.68912, -1.69027, -1.69856, 
    -1.70366, -1.70891, -1.7159, -1.71791, -1.72226, -1.72897, 
    -1.73228, -1.72881, -1.72264, -1.7296, -1.73507, -1.74244, 
    -1.75018, -1.75639, -1.76753, -1.77342, -1.77948, -1.78742, 
    -1.79492, -1.80031, -1.7946, -1.78451, -1.77937, -1.77577, 
    -1.76931, -1.76427, -1.76093, -1.75392, -1.74629, -1.73849, 
    -1.72856, -1.72277, -1.71514, -1.71024, -1.70519, -1.69971, 
    -1.69504, -1.69394, -1.69641, -1.7037, -1.70494, -1.70367, 
    -1.70659, -1.70492, -1.70796, -1.70796, -1.70657, -1.71111, 
    -1.70728, -1.71203, -1.70145, -1.69333, -1.68797, -1.68233, 
    -1.67685, -1.6678, -1.66168, -1.65713, -1.64816, -1.64269, 
    -1.64206, -1.64641, -1.65156, -1.65644, -1.66524, -1.67325, 
    -1.6774, -1.68163, -1.67623, -1.66331, -1.65847, -1.63958, 
    -1.63662, -1.63215, -1.62674, -1.62326, -1.6181, -1.6106, 
    -1.60594, -1.60151, -1.5898, -1.58363, -1.57944, -1.57365, 
    -1.56631, -1.55921, -1.55559, -1.55121, -1.54627, -1.54072, 
    -1.53395, -1.51731, -1.51319, -1.50591, -1.50127, -1.49576, 
    -1.49034, -1.4879, -1.48094, -1.46184, -1.45457, -1.44341, 
    -1.43462, -1.4282, -1.42304, -1.41192, -1.40148, -1.3961, 
    -1.38166, -1.37602, -1.36789, -1.36097, -1.35642, -1.34003, 
    -1.33331, -1.32801, -1.32303, -1.31586, -1.31218, -1.30768, 
    -1.30144, -1.29669, -1.29241, -1.2919, -1.29807, -1.30673, 
    -1.31375, -1.31358, -1.31167, -1.31357, -1.31481, -1.31238, 
    -1.30754, -1.30357, -1.31034, -1.31531, -1.33604, -1.33119, 
    -1.32594, -1.3265, -1.33228, -1.34208, -1.34269, -1.34696, 
    -1.35291, -1.3315, -1.3232, -1.31535, -1.31474, -1.31963, 
    -1.31555, -1.32074, -1.31996, -1.31672, -1.31809, -1.32221, 
    -1.31383, -1.30195, -1.30113, -1.30087, -1.30525, -1.30036, 
    -1.30522, -1.30893, -1.30856, 53.93439, 53.93513, 53.9366, 
    53.93803, 53.93951, 53.94085, 53.93954, 53.94498, 53.94499, 
    53.94369, 53.94152, 53.94308, 53.941, 53.94052, 53.94305, 
    53.94146, 53.93654, 53.9355, 53.92837, 53.92816, 53.92894, 
    53.92639, 53.92086, 53.91613, 53.91021, 53.91394, 53.90971, 
    53.90717, 53.90736, 53.90702, 53.91105, 53.91161, 53.9108, 
    53.91198, 53.91519, 53.91492, 53.91142, 53.91182, 53.91136, 
    53.90874, 53.91024, 53.91005, 53.91074, 53.90305, 53.90491, 
    53.90396, 53.91084, 53.9072, 53.90129, 53.90203, 53.90689, 
    53.90903, 53.90622, 53.90359, 53.90536, 53.90558, 53.9074, 
    53.90596, 53.90691, 53.91252, 53.91314, 53.9113, 53.91037, 
    53.91063, 53.91268, 53.91744, 53.91683, 53.91872, 53.91807, 
    53.91763, 53.90858, 53.91199, 53.91036, 53.90001, 53.89485, 
    53.89087, 53.88638, 53.88703, 53.88491, 53.8852, 53.8847, 
    53.8898, 53.88907, 53.89123, 53.89694, 53.89466, 53.88595, 
    53.88056, 53.88057, 53.87441, 53.87064, 53.86733, 53.86702, 
    53.86388, 53.86605, 53.86343, 53.86447, 53.86501, 53.86487, 
    53.86627, 53.86353, 53.86107, 53.85779, 53.85757, 53.85132, 
    53.84736, 53.84233, 53.83714, 53.83257, 53.82862, 53.82322, 
    53.81573, 53.80983, 53.80412, 53.79164, 53.78774, 53.78313, 
    53.78352, 53.78438, 53.78582, 53.78649, 53.78127, 53.77925, 
    53.77972, 53.78017, 53.77996, 53.78016, 53.77282, 53.7715, 
    53.76739, 53.76728, 53.76404, 53.76204, 53.76019, 53.75653, 
    53.7538, 53.74738, 53.74676, 53.74784, 53.74007, 53.73082, 
    53.72382, 53.71862, 53.71899, 53.72106, 53.72089, 53.71982, 
    53.71794, 53.71615, 53.71218, 53.70858, 53.70413, 53.69903, 
    53.70277, 53.70639, 53.71057, 53.71306, 53.71485, 53.72469, 
    53.72757, 53.72711, 53.72372, 53.72237, 53.72246, 53.72777, 
    53.72784, 53.72804, 53.7281, 53.72821, 53.7257, 53.72137, 
    53.72356, 53.72313, 53.7197, 53.72279, 53.72665, 53.72953, 
    53.72964, 53.73197, 53.73156, 53.73639, 53.7357, 53.73662, 
    53.73486, 53.73976, 53.75592, 53.75518, 53.75576, 53.75898, 
    53.76152, 53.76723, 53.77284, 53.77307, 53.78159, 53.78612, 
    53.79548, 53.80091, 53.80959, 53.81441, 53.81366, 53.81657, 
    53.81995, 53.82363, 53.83362, 53.83551, 53.83593, 53.84046, 
    53.84099, 53.84521, 53.85155, 53.85422, 53.85678, 53.86157, 
    53.86171, 53.86338, 53.86871, 53.87899, 53.88171, 53.88382, 
    53.88856, 53.89206, 53.89758, 53.90049, 53.90504, 53.90972, 
    53.91458, 53.9224, 53.92119, 53.92945, 53.92716, 53.92413, 
    53.93439), .Dim = c(232L, 2L))), list(structure(c(-1.31586, 
    -1.3097, -1.30377, -1.30998, -1.31586, 53.73976, 53.7396, 
    53.74192, 53.74457, 53.73976), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", 
    "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", "sfc"
    ), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -1.80031, ymin = 53.69903, 
    xmax = -1.2919, ymax = 53.94499), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
        input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(URAU_CODE = NA_integer_, 
URAU_CATG = NA_integer_, CNTR_CODE = NA_integer_, URAU_NAME = NA_integer_, 
CITY_CPTL = NA_integer_, CITY_KERN = NA_integer_, FUA_CODE = NA_integer_, 
NUTS3_2016 = NA_integer_, FID = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = 3L, class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"))
```

[image]

- U:  multipolygon dataframe with 728 observations of functional urban areas around Europe

```
structure(list(URAU_CODE = "FR032L2", URAU_CATG = "F", CNTR_CODE = "F", 
    URAU_NAME = "FUA of Toulon", CITY_CPTL = NA_integer_, CITY_KERN = NA_integer_, 
    FUA_CODE = NA_integer_, NUTS3_2016 = "FRL05", FID = "FR032L2", 
    geometry = structure(list(structure(list(list(structure(c(5.91095, 
    5.91566, 5.9127, 5.91095, 43.11508, 43.11776, 43.12294, 43.11508
    ), .Dim = c(4L, 2L))), list(structure(c(5.90748, 5.9127, 
    5.91756, 5.9223, 5.92636, 5.93393, 5.92611, 5.93023, 5.92529, 
    5.93118, 5.93591, 5.94095, 5.94603, 5.95276, 5.95744, 5.96315, 
    5.96842, 5.97351, 5.97906, 5.98509, 5.99149, 5.99736, 6.00222, 
    6.01296, 6.01823, 6.02347, 6.0241, 6.0207, 6.0168, 6.02124, 
    6.02715, 6.03253, 6.03817, 6.05012, 6.05635, 6.06314, 6.06867, 
    6.07467, 6.07878, 6.08528, 6.09978, 6.10878, 6.11399, 6.11902, 
    6.12489, 6.1279, 6.13306, 6.13167, 6.12912, 6.12556, 6.11937, 
    6.10622, 6.10129, 6.09403, 6.09104, 6.09518, 6.10003, 6.10505, 
    6.10966, 6.11305, 6.11974, 6.1242, 6.12697, 6.13151, 6.1362, 
    6.1419, 6.14512, 6.14984, 6.15465, 6.15923, 6.16548, 6.16772, 
    6.16205, 6.15622, 6.15211, 6.15002, 6.14947, 6.15033, 6.15269, 
    6.15342, 6.15495, 6.15818, 6.1599, 6.17052, 6.17911, 6.19208, 
    6.20163, 6.21141, 6.22437, 6.23434, 6.23023, 6.22452, 6.2194, 
    6.19509, 6.19442, 6.19923, 6.20134, 6.20145, 6.19795, 6.2038, 
    6.19648, 6.19324, 6.18682, 6.18195, 6.17694, 6.17044, 6.16838, 
    6.16139, 6.15859, 6.16316, 6.18003, 6.19447, 6.19987, 6.2074, 
    6.215, 6.22049, 6.23336, 6.23822, 6.23984, 6.23925, 6.24043, 
    6.24434, 6.2474, 6.24924, 6.24668, 6.24723, 6.2535, 6.26133, 
    6.26586, 6.27247, 6.28057, 6.28784, 6.29226, 6.29663, 6.30184, 
    6.30873, 6.29846, 6.29281, 6.28497, 6.2789, 6.2785, 6.27525, 
    6.26829, 6.25807, 6.25451, 6.24885, 6.23384, 6.22896, 6.23175, 
    6.22991, 6.22439, 6.21351, 6.20894, 6.20305, 6.19689, 6.18993, 
    6.18436, 6.17524, 6.16898, 6.16237, 6.15232, 6.14667, 6.13835, 
    6.14094, 6.13984, 6.13721, 6.13381, 6.13437, 6.13581, 6.13944, 
    6.13755, 6.13108, 6.12569, 6.12117, 6.11296, 6.10449, 6.11283, 
    6.10901, 6.10911, 6.11198, 6.11056, 6.11031, 6.10137, 6.09218, 
    6.08483, 6.07942, 6.07489, 6.06559, 6.06159, 6.05755, 6.05407, 
    6.05728, 6.05072, 6.04416, 6.03451, 6.03017, 6.02087, 6.01612, 
    6.01161, 6.00176, 5.99488, 5.99114, 5.98671, 5.97833, 5.97318, 
    5.96788, 5.96177, 5.95575, 5.95448, 5.95462, 5.95851, 5.95471, 
    5.95075, 5.93836, 5.93313, 5.92314, 5.92581, 5.93355, 5.93472, 
    5.93017, 5.92982, 5.93346, 5.93216, 5.93186, 5.93022, 5.92926, 
    5.93959, 5.92581, 5.91511, 5.90145, 5.89125, 5.88674, 5.87769, 
    5.86558, 5.85955, 5.85512, 5.85238, 5.84883, 5.83823, 5.82502, 
    5.81324, 5.80664, 5.80177, 5.78974, 5.78371, 5.776, 5.77038, 
    5.76624, 5.76093, 5.75634, 5.74626, 5.74073, 5.73491, 5.73273, 
    5.72316, 5.71752, 5.71147, 5.70891, 5.70122, 5.7024, 5.68241, 
    5.6805, 5.67799, 5.67854, 5.67596, 5.68165, 5.68658, 5.69537, 
    5.69848, 5.70469, 5.71126, 5.71906, 5.72673, 5.73035, 5.72954, 
    5.72912, 5.72752, 5.73145, 5.7337, 5.72877, 5.73689, 5.72764, 
    5.72823, 5.72635, 5.7233, 5.72805, 5.73334, 5.73827, 5.74421, 
    5.7489, 5.75407, 5.75738, 5.76257, 5.76778, 5.7719, 5.77814, 
    5.78065, 5.77341, 5.77331, 5.77765, 5.7832, 5.78785, 5.79924, 
    5.80473, 5.81141, 5.81211, 5.80867, 5.81211, 5.80727, 5.80504, 
    5.80341, 5.79584, 5.79338, 5.79845, 5.80315, 5.80929, 5.81545, 
    5.8181, 5.8215, 5.827, 5.83112, 5.8385, 5.84377, 5.85216, 
    5.85708, 5.86202, 5.86419, 5.86798, 5.87089, 5.87571, 5.88059, 
    5.88713, 5.89286, 5.899, 5.90585, 5.90758, 5.90247, 5.89571, 
    5.88577, 5.88038, 5.89172, 5.88452, 5.88574, 5.88965, 5.89454, 
    5.89752, 5.91095, 5.90748, 43.11888, 43.12294, 43.12185, 
    43.11894, 43.12089, 43.11686, 43.11558, 43.11361, 43.10282, 
    43.10267, 43.10689, 43.10776, 43.10742, 43.10684, 43.10804, 
    43.10691, 43.1035, 43.10734, 43.10654, 43.10661, 43.10379, 
    43.10733, 43.10326, 43.10093, 43.09877, 43.09481, 43.09011, 
    43.08675, 43.08328, 43.07849, 43.07879, 43.07771, 43.07893, 
    43.07943, 43.08085, 43.08328, 43.08309, 43.08385, 43.08771, 
    43.08651, 43.08332, 43.08392, 43.08365, 43.0806, 43.07892, 
    43.07309, 43.05643, 43.04805, 43.04373, 43.04091, 43.03901, 
    43.04089, 43.0407, 43.04048, 43.03572, 43.02923, 43.02916, 
    43.03092, 43.03208, 43.03525, 43.03305, 43.03177, 43.03578, 
    43.03485, 43.03407, 43.03004, 43.02669, 43.02743, 43.02785, 
    43.02945, 43.03109, 43.03534, 43.03405, 43.03501, 43.03723, 
    43.0459, 43.05659, 43.0645, 43.07058, 43.07529, 43.08011, 
    43.0836, 43.08849, 43.0998, 43.10613, 43.10997, 43.11609, 
    43.1161, 43.11399, 43.11306, 43.11983, 43.12295, 43.12457, 
    43.12541, 43.13489, 43.13707, 43.14596, 43.15259, 43.15667, 
    43.16147, 43.17005, 43.17345, 43.178, 43.18636, 43.18604, 
    43.18748, 43.19192, 43.19419, 43.19784, 43.20264, 43.20175, 
    43.20499, 43.20571, 43.205, 43.20722, 43.20843, 43.21123, 
    43.21484, 43.22463, 43.2317, 43.24036, 43.24266, 43.248, 
    43.25253, 43.2587, 43.2644, 43.26509, 43.26423, 43.26267, 
    43.26285, 43.26328, 43.26468, 43.26758, 43.26967, 43.27155, 
    43.26951, 43.27739, 43.28353, 43.29493, 43.29901, 43.30409, 
    43.30722, 43.31869, 43.32102, 43.33066, 43.33374, 43.33468, 
    43.33836, 43.34415, 43.35011, 43.3536, 43.35541, 43.36007, 
    43.35974, 43.36175, 43.36325, 43.36763, 43.37083, 43.37154, 
    43.3687, 43.36502, 43.36005, 43.35892, 43.35496, 43.34828, 
    43.34377, 43.33738, 43.33211, 43.3276, 43.31657, 43.30813, 
    43.30943, 43.30893, 43.30872, 43.31751, 43.322, 43.32201, 
    43.32726, 43.33517, 43.34205, 43.34805, 43.35283, 43.35214, 
    43.35037, 43.34827, 43.34859, 43.34716, 43.34567, 43.34287, 
    43.35031, 43.35897, 43.36279, 43.36571, 43.36453, 43.36525, 
    43.36788, 43.36865, 43.37023, 43.36947, 43.36988, 43.37102, 
    43.36754, 43.36289, 43.3623, 43.36283, 43.36413, 43.36208, 
    43.35655, 43.35077, 43.34482, 43.34087, 43.33617, 43.32981, 
    43.32386, 43.31803, 43.31583, 43.31015, 43.30748, 43.30113, 
    43.29835, 43.28935, 43.28216, 43.25855, 43.25325, 43.24244, 
    43.23044, 43.21597, 43.21718, 43.21729, 43.21533, 43.21269, 
    43.21312, 43.21252, 43.21498, 43.22156, 43.22995, 43.23485, 
    43.2383, 43.24241, 43.247, 43.24852, 43.25051, 43.25349, 
    43.2576, 43.25986, 43.26415, 43.26508, 43.26809, 43.26734, 
    43.26634, 43.26408, 43.26245, 43.26171, 43.25767, 43.25705, 
    43.25481, 43.25332, 43.24933, 43.24715, 43.23917, 43.23545, 
    43.22927, 43.21978, 43.20515, 43.19064, 43.19236, 43.19136, 
    43.19127, 43.19595, 43.19717, 43.20003, 43.202, 43.20361, 
    43.20022, 43.18795, 43.17936, 43.17382, 43.16952, 43.16557, 
    43.16004, 43.1588, 43.15489, 43.14705, 43.14111, 43.13728, 
    43.13515, 43.1363, 43.13534, 43.13498, 43.13191, 43.13099, 
    43.13607, 43.13772, 43.1426, 43.1404, 43.13553, 43.13112, 
    43.12599, 43.11995, 43.11635, 43.11645, 43.11298, 43.11524, 
    43.11462, 43.11198, 43.10493, 43.09851, 43.09543, 43.09242, 
    43.08578, 43.07863, 43.07436, 43.06767, 43.06846, 43.06678, 
    43.06569, 43.06267, 43.05754, 43.05365, 43.05208, 43.04898, 
    43.04916, 43.04782, 43.04949, 43.04763, 43.05342, 43.0579, 
    43.06174, 43.06526, 43.0688, 43.07261, 43.07723, 43.07835, 
    43.08784, 43.09338, 43.0977, 43.10377, 43.10285, 43.10524, 
    43.10545, 43.10798, 43.11335, 43.11835, 43.11584, 43.11722, 
    43.11361, 43.11508, 43.11888), .Dim = c(348L, 2L))), list(
        structure(c(5.89932, 5.90695, 5.91119, 5.92146, 5.92658, 
        5.93237, 5.9375, 5.94424, 5.9511, 5.94936, 5.94408, 5.9379, 
        5.92895, 5.92463, 5.92162, 5.91652, 5.91238, 5.90768, 
        5.90318, 5.89776, 5.89932, 43.07431, 43.07258, 43.06633, 
        43.06861, 43.06984, 43.07115, 43.07066, 43.06631, 43.07203, 
        43.07884, 43.08199, 43.08457, 43.08292, 43.07824, 43.08459, 
        43.08566, 43.08318, 43.07766, 43.07726, 43.08031, 43.07431
        ), .Dim = c(21L, 2L))), list(structure(c(6.16904, 6.17719, 
    6.18009, 6.18452, 6.19048, 6.19517, 6.20284, 6.20911, 6.21337, 
    6.21678, 6.22156, 6.22722, 6.23122, 6.23602, 6.2419, 6.24641, 
    6.24944, 6.24901, 6.24841, 6.24365, 6.23941, 6.23626, 6.23406, 
    6.2257, 6.221, 6.21622, 6.21398, 6.20653, 6.20175, 6.19701, 
    6.19297, 6.18825, 6.18575, 6.18112, 6.177, 6.17176, 6.1689, 
    6.16904, 42.99808, 42.99694, 42.99329, 42.9916, 42.99076, 
    42.98538, 42.9825, 42.98553, 42.98786, 42.99125, 42.99208, 
    42.99234, 42.99535, 42.99649, 42.99818, 42.99766, 43.00359, 
    43.00847, 43.01341, 43.02046, 43.02512, 43.01825, 43.0117, 
    43.01149, 43.01288, 43.01218, 43.00401, 43.00283, 43.00087, 
    43.00172, 43.00564, 43.00396, 43.00801, 43.00852, 43.0065, 
    43.00718, 43.00264, 42.99808), .Dim = c(38L, 2L))), list(
        structure(c(6.49575, 6.48995, 6.48374, 6.47806, 6.47284, 
        6.46677, 6.46116, 6.45965, 6.45589, 6.45045, 6.44586, 
        6.44071, 6.43677, 6.43374, 6.43268, 6.43556, 6.44073, 
        6.44534, 6.44868, 6.45184, 6.4555, 6.45983, 6.4644, 6.46882, 
        6.4727, 6.47715, 6.48069, 6.48407, 6.4877, 6.49247, 6.49666, 
        6.5015, 6.50801, 6.50725, 6.50244, 6.49575, 43.05006, 
        43.04892, 43.04699, 43.04742, 43.04573, 43.04136, 43.03565, 
        43.02981, 43.02701, 43.0264, 43.02491, 43.0251, 43.02123, 
        43.01719, 43.01074, 43.00532, 43.00626, 43.01001, 43.01313, 
        43.01802, 43.01478, 43.01349, 43.01486, 43.01748, 43.02306, 
        43.02718, 43.03215, 43.03846, 43.04202, 43.04077, 43.04282, 
        43.04255, 43.04712, 43.05202, 43.05184, 43.05006), .Dim = c(36L, 
        2L))), list(structure(c(6.39871, 6.3922, 6.38777, 6.38274, 
    6.37708, 6.37437, 6.36905, 6.37078, 6.37738, 6.38352, 6.38997, 
    6.39468, 6.4006, 6.40666, 6.40976, 6.41351, 6.4177, 6.41685, 
    6.41158, 6.41428, 6.41027, 6.40507, 6.39871, 43.01505, 43.01316, 
    43.01215, 43.01233, 43.00745, 43.00384, 43.00219, 42.99785, 
    42.99716, 42.99739, 42.99743, 42.99523, 42.99475, 42.9956, 
    43.00036, 43.00414, 43.00719, 43.01173, 43.01188, 43.01556, 
    43.01891, 43.01742, 43.01505), .Dim = c(23L, 2L))), list(
        structure(c(5.79114, 5.78602, 5.78128, 5.7774, 5.77762, 
        5.77883, 5.78373, 5.78735, 5.79114, 43.07909, 43.0788, 
        43.07876, 43.08177, 43.07478, 43.0701, 43.07108, 43.07403, 
        43.07909), .Dim = c(9L, 2L))), list(structure(c(6.35965, 
    6.35925, 6.36383, 6.3638, 6.36764, 6.36178, 6.35965, 43.01302, 
    43.00808, 43.004, 43.00995, 43.01513, 43.01746, 43.01302), .Dim = c(7L, 
    2L))), list(structure(c(6.14318, 6.14706, 6.13969, 6.14318, 
    43.01644, 43.01946, 43.0194, 43.01644), .Dim = c(4L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", 
    "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTIPOLYGON", "sfc"
    ), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 5.67596, ymin = 42.9825, 
    xmax = 6.50801, ymax = 43.37154), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
        input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(URAU_CODE = NA_integer_, 
URAU_CATG = NA_integer_, CNTR_CODE = NA_integer_, URAU_NAME = NA_integer_, 
CITY_CPTL = NA_integer_, CITY_KERN = NA_integer_, FUA_CODE = NA_integer_, 
NUTS3_2016 = NA_integer_, FID = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = 2L, class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"))
```

[image]

Functional urban areas include city centers but are larger, and not every city has one.

My task is two compute the "donut-shaped" FUA areas that are not city centers.

Naively, I tried with `st_difference(U,C)` but it is taking forever to complete the task. Can someone help me out with this?

Many thanks

Comment: Try `sf::sf_use_s2(FALSE)` and tell me if it works better ;)

Comment: I tried also this method but unfortunately it gave me another error. Anyway, I solved the issue with `rmapshaper::ms_erase`